# Unable to access Iframe control in crm 2016 form

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2016

I am upgrading crm 2011 to crm 2016 onpremise, due to new rendering engine of newer version so many javascript code is not working. Recently getting issue with iframe where I am unable accessing iframe contents using JQuery.

`var ccControl = $("#WebResource_ccCheckList").contents().find(":checkbox");
 if(ccControl)
{
 //Business Logic
}`

The element I want to access is an html input with id of 'myChckboxId':
 Are you Agree ?
getting ReferenceError: '$' is undefined Error although $ reference working fine with scripted in IFrame.
tried following workaround to fix but not working for me :

1)Put following script on onload.

`if (typeof($) === 'undefined'){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js';
    script.async = false; 
    document.head.appendChild(script);}`

2)
`$(Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('WebResource_ccCheckList').getObject()).contents().find(':checkbox').val();`
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('WebResource_ccCheckList').getObject() is giving me obj but not works with $.

3)
`Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("WebResource_ccCheckList").getObject().contentWindow.document.getElementById('myChckboxId');`

Getting Null

Please suggest any alternate approach to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is still there, it's just above you:

```
$ = ($ || parent.$); 
// Now you have $
```

Comment: Mandatory warning: manipulating the DOM is never a good idea (with each update the code might need to be rewritten from scratch)